# How to use multiple conditions in $filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Below is my mongoDB data

```
 {
                        "_id": "SG01",
                        "name": "Pawan",
                        "marks": [
                            {
                                "English": 93,
                                "Maths": 90,
                                "Hindi": 89,
                                "Sci": 98
                            }
                        ],
                        "__v": 0
                    }

      {
                        "_id": "SG02",
                        "name": "Dravid",
                        "marks": [
                            {
                                "English": 40,
                                "Maths": 67,
                                "Hindi": 56,
                                "Sci": 45
                            }
                        ],
                        "__v": 0
                    }
      {
                        "_id": "SG03",
                        "name": "Kartik",
                        "marks": [
                            {
                                "English": 65,
                                "Maths": 77,
                                "Hindi": 80,
                                "Sci": 79
                            }
                        ],
                        "__v": 0
                    }
```

I want to show the details of those students who are having numbers greater than a particalur value in more than (or equal to) two subjects. for instance students having **maths marks** as well as **Sci  marks** greater than 89. I'm able to find out for one subject but not more than one . Below is the code for that

```
   {

det.aggregate([
  {
     $project: {
       _id:0,name:1,
        marks:[ {
           $filter: {
              input: "$marks",
              as:"mark",
        cond: { $gte: [ "$$mark.Maths",89]}
           }
        }]
     }
  }
],function(err,data){
  if(err)
  res.json({message:err});
  else {
    res.json({data:data});
  }
})


   }
```

I tried **$and** but failed to get the result . Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
this is how I'm doing.. The find() part is running smoothly on Robo Mongo 
but when I'm trying to return the document using POSTMAN...

```
det.find({ marks:{ $elemMatch:{ Maths: { $gt :20 ,$lt :90}}}},function(err,data){
console.log(err,data)
    if(err)
        res.json({err});
    else {
        res.json({data});
    }
  })
```

It is giving error with no message then I tried to get the o/p on the console.below is the error

```
Listeneing at port 8080
Error: Can't use $elemMatch with Number.
    at SchemaNumber.castForQuery (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/number.js:278:13)
    at SchemaNumber.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1059:17)
    at cast (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:282:39)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3198:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1278:10)
    at model.Query.Query._find (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1293:8)
    at model.Query.Query.find (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1375:8)
    at Function.find (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1365:13)
    at peel (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/employee/dbms2.js:146:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/pawankumar/Pawan/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) undefined
```

Comment: Try `det.find({}, {_id:0, name:1, marks:{$elemMatch:{Maths:{$gt:89}, Sci:{$gt:89}}} )` for a single match in a array.

Comment: Can you please post the code which you tried with $and

Comment: I think your data model is wrong.  Your "marks" is an array but it has a single document in every case that's structured as "subject":"grade" key-value subdocument.  I'm sure you meant either one or the other.  Unless the idea is that first element (__v:0) is grades at one point and then later you will push another document into the array for __v:1 - in which case your filter has to specify which version grades you actually want.  But in your case __v is on the top level document.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the $elemMatch operator

```
db.collection.find({ "marks": { "$elemMatch": { "Math": {"$gt":70, "$lt":100}, "Sci": 79 }}})
```

Comment: can't we use it with aggregate.... and how to use lte or gte....  kindly do post it how to use it using lte or gte.. itwould be great help..

Comment: Sir.. I've edited the post... please do check .. any sort of help is appreciated :)

Comment: Where Sir? I haven't used any... i mean i've used like { Maths: { $gt :20 ,$lt :90}}}} but still no result

Comment: Sir , I guess Im not having enough credits to join a chat

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why "marks" is an array in your schema since it only ever has one element of `{subject:grade}` fields, but for that exact schema you would query like this (you need at least 3.6 to use `$expr` in `find`:

```
db.det.find({$expr:{$gt:[
    {$size: {$filter:{
        input:{$objectToArray:{$arrayElemAt:["$marks",0]}}, 
        cond:{$gt:["$$this.v", 89]} 
    }}},
    0
]}})
```